# List of tuples: combine two dataframe columns if first tuple elements match

Tags: python, pandas, itertools-groupby

I have two separate lists each of `n` elements, with one being ID numbers and the second being pandas dataframes. I will define them as `id` and `dfs`. The dataframes in `dfs` have the same format with columns `A`, `B`, and `C` but with different numerical values. I have zipped the two lists together as such:

```
df_groups = list(zip(id, dfs))
```

With this list I am trying to locate any instances where `id` is the same and then add columns `A` and `B` together for those dataframes and merge into one dataframe. For an example, I will use the following:

```
id = ['a','b','c','a','d']
```

The corresponding dataframes I have may look as such:

```
dfs[0]
A  B  C
0  0  1
0  0  1

dfs[1]
A  B  C
0  1  1
0  1  1

dfs[2]
A  B  C
1  1  1
1  2  1

dfs[3]
A  B  C
5  6  1
11 8  1

dfs[4]
A  B  C
3  5  2
3  18 2
```

Then, as can be seen above, `id[0]` is the same as `id[3]`. As such, I want to create a new list of tuples such that `dfs[0]['A']` and `dfs[3]['A']` are added together (similarly also for column `B` and the duplicate `id` value is dropped.

Thus, it should look like this:

```
id = ['a','b','c','d']

dfs[0]
A  B  C
5  6  1
11 8  1

dfs[1]
A  B  C
0  1  1
0  1  1

dfs[2]
A  B  C
1  1  1
1  2  1

dfs[3]
A  B  C
3  5  2
3  18 2
```

The following worked for removing the duplicate values of `id` but I am not quite sure how to go about the column operations on `dfs`. I will of course need to add the columns `A` and `B` first before running the below:

```
from itertools import groupby

df_groups_b = ([next(b) for a, b in groupby(df_groups, lambda x: x[0])])
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated, thank you!

Edit: to clarify, column C from the original dataframe would be retained as is. In the case where the first tuple elements match, column C from the corresponding dataframes will be identical.

Comment: Do you want to leave column `C` as in first dataframe occured? Or add values together too, as for `A` and `B`?

Comment: @MariaK Yes, column C would be left as is from the original dataframe. Only columns A and B would be added.

Comment: Note that `groupby` only groups consecutive entries, so you should first sort def_groups with the same key `lambda x: x[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a custom summarising function to go through all dataframes in a group and return a sum.

I don't entirely love this solution, because in converts `C` to float, but you can play with it further if needed:

```py
from itertools import groupby
import pandas as pd

ids = ['a','b','c','a','d']
dfs = [
    pd.DataFrame({"A": [0], "B": [0], "C": [0]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"A": [1], "B": [1], "C": [1]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"A": [2], "B": [2], "C": [2]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"A": [3], "B": [3], "C": [3]}),
    pd.DataFrame({"A": [4], "B": [4], "C": [4]})
]
df_groups = list(zip(ids, dfs))
df_groups = sorted(df_groups, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

```py
def summarise_cols(group, cols_to_summarise=["A", "B"]):
    _, df = next(group)
    for _, next_df in group:
        df = df.add(next_df[cols_to_summarise], fill_value=0)
    return df

df_groups_b = ([summarise_cols(group)
                for _, group in groupby(df_groups, lambda x: x[0])])

for d in df_groups_b:
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
   A  B    C
0  3  3  0.0
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
   A  B  C
0  2  2  2
   A  B  C
0  4  4  4
```

**UPD:** just noticed your update

> Edit: to clarify, column C from the original dataframe would be retained as is. In the case where the first tuple elements match, column C from the corresponding dataframes will be identical.

You can then do this instead and the column types will be unchanged

```
def summarise_cols(group, cols_to_keep=["C"]):
    _, df = next(group)
    for _, next_df in group:
        df += next_df
        df[cols_to_keep] = next_df[cols_to_keep]
    return df
```

**UPD2:** Returning group_id and unified dataframe together as a tuple.

```
def summarise_cols(group, cols_to_keep=["C"]):
    group_id, df = next(group)
    for _, next_df in group:
        df += next_df
        df[cols_to_keep] = next_df[cols_to_keep]
    return group_id, df
```

Comment: And yes as @Swifty noted in the comments, I sorted the list before grouping

Comment: Updated the answer to keep `C` dtype intact.

Comment: You could probably get rid of summarise_cols with `sum(group)` followed by restoring col 'C'.

Comment: I tried, but didn't come up with a nice one-liner, because `group` is a tuple. Do you have anything specific in mind?

Comment: I just hit the same problem! I had forgotten that group was a tuple, sorry about that. Ok, you can solve the summing problem with `sum(map(lambda x: x[1], group))`

Comment: Thank you for this code! The option you show keeping column `C` the same is displaying the dataframes consolidated as intended. However, the answer is only showing a list of dataframes and not the tuple also containing the consolidated `id` elements. The consolidated `id` element names are required as I later use them when exporting the final dataframes.

Comment: @verynovice, updated the answer to return `(group_id, dataframe)` as a tuple. Will this work for you?

Comment: @MariaK yes that worked, thank you very much! Everything is now operating as intended and will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use pandas grouping:

```
a = (pd.concat([d.assign(id = i).reset_index() for i, d in df_groups])
       .groupby(['id', 'index'])
       .agg({'A':'sum', 'B':'sum', 'C':'first'})
       .reset_index(0).rename_axis(index = {'index':''})
       .pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(x.pop('id'))))

new_id, new_df_groups = zip(*a)
print(new_id)

('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

for d in new_df_groups:
  print(d, "\n\n")

    A  B  C
0   5  6  1
1  11  8  1

   A  B  C
0  0  1  1
1  0  1  1

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  1

   A   B  C
0  3   5  2
1  3  18  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of repeated ids using a dict, then join them using `concat` and `groupby`:

```
def add_dfs(df1: pd.DataFrame, df2: pd.DataFrame):
    to_sum = ["A", "B"]
    df = pd.concat([df1.loc[:, to_sum], df2[to_sum]]).reset_index()
    df = (
        df.groupby("index")
        .sum()
        .reset_index()
        .merge(df1["C"].reset_index(), how="left", on="index")
        .drop(columns="index")
    )
    return df


d = {}

for id, df in zip(id, dfs):
    if id not in d.keys():
        d[id] = df
    else:
        df2 = d[id]
        df = add_dfs(df, df2)
        d[id] = df

dfs = list(d.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) then use a simple dictionary comprehension with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
ids = ['a','b','c','a','d']

out = {k: g.groupby(level=1).agg(dict.fromkeys(g.columns, 'sum')|{'C': 'first'})
       for k,g in pd.concat(dfs, keys=ids, names=['id', None]).groupby('id')}
```

*NB. `dict.fromkeys(g.columns, 'sum')|{'C': 'first'}` is creating `{'A': 'sum', 'B': 'sum', 'C': 'first'}` programmatically. All columns as `'sum'`, except `C` as `'first'`.*

Or with pure python to group the dataframes with the same id (will be more memory efficient for many dfs:

```
d = {}
for k, df in zip(ids, dfs):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(df)
    
out = {k: pd.concat(v).groupby(level=0)
            .agg({'A': 'sum', 'B': 'sum', 'C': 'first'})
       for k, v in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a':     A  B  C
      0   5  6  1
      1  11  8  1,
 'b':    A  B  C
      0  0  1  1
      1  0  1  1,
 'c':    A  B  C
      0  1  1  1
      1  1  2  1,
 'd':    A   B  C
      0  3   5  2
      1  3  18  2}
```